# list of friend not being display using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a list of friend that i want to show on each profile page  where the user is friend with them but the problem is that when i use firebug the system display one id and with a default piture

so i think the error is in the foreach loop can anyone help me ????

## php code:

```
<?php 
//***********************Displaying Friend List*************************//
$friendListTitle = "";
$friendList = "";
if($friend_array!="")
{
    $friendArray = explode(",", $friend_array);

    $friendArray = array_slice($friendArray,0,6);
    $friendCount = count($friendArray); 
    var_dump($friendCount);
    $friendListTitle = '<div class="title"> '.$username.'\'s Friends('.$friendCount.')</div>';
        //iterating to retrieve what it's needed as values
/*$frnd1 = $friendArray[0];
$frnd2 = $friendArray[1];
/*$frnd3 = $friendArray[2];
$frnd4 = $friendArray[3];
$friendList .='<div style="background-color:"#CCC";>'.$frnd1.'<br />'.$frnd2.'</div>';*/

        $i=0;
        $friendList .='<div  style="background-color:"#CCC"; >'; 
        foreach($friendArray as $key => $value)
        {
            $i++;
            $check_pic = "members/$value/image01.jpg";
            if(file_exists($check_pic))
            {
                $frnd_pic = '<a href="profile.php?id='.$value.'"><img src = \"$check_pic\" width = \"30px\"; border = \"1\"/></a>';
            }
            else
            {
                $frnd_pic = '<a href="profile.php?id='.$value.'"><img src = "members/0/image01.jpg" width = \"30px\" border = \"1\"/></a>&nbsp;';
            }
            $sqlName = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM members WHERE user_id= '$value' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlName))
            {
                $fname = $row['first_name'];
                $lname = $row['last_name'];
                $friendList = '<div title="'.$fname.' '.$lname.'">'.$frnd_pic.'</div>';
            }
        }
        $friendList .='</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed one dot. Please look at this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlName))
            {
                $fname = $row['first_name'];
                $lname = $row['last_name'];
                $friendList .= '<div title="'.$fname.' '.$lname.'">'.$frnd_pic.'</div>';
            }
```

because the varibale's name (`$friendList`) you need to make some string concatenation not simple substitution.
If You use substitution then everythinh what you have collected in `$friendList` will be lost.
The main problem was in this line:

```
$friendList .= '<div title="'.$fname.' '.$lname.'">'.$frnd_pic.'</div>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your html table structure is broken:

add closing bracket here `<table border = "0" align="center" cellpadding="3"`, add td tags, put tr tags into loop

also, replace 
    `if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlName,MYSQL_ASSOC))` 
with
    `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlName,MYSQL_ASSOC))`

Comment: and still having the same problemmmmmm